# For which other matrix expressions of the form $P'AQ''$ are there as clear, intuitive geometric interpretations as for the change of basis $PAP^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

The matrix expression of the form $PAP^{-1}$, a similarity transform, has a clear and intuitive geometric meaning as simply changing the basis with $P^{-1}$, performing the transformation $A$ and then transforming back into the original basis using $P$.

But suppose one considers all the various valid possibilities for a square matrix (other than null, or unit matrix) sandwiched between a pair of matrices $P$ and $Q$ in any combination of diagonal, transpose, symmetric, skew-symmetric, complex, Hermitian, adjoint etc?

**Which other such $P'AQ''$ expressions also have a clear and intuitive geometric interpretation.**

(But if the question is trivial because professional mathematicians can easily 'see' the geometric interpretation of any such combination, then perhaps someone could answer the more general case where the matrices are not square but still conforming to the requisite indices (nxm)x(mxp)x(pxq) allowing e.g. vectors and column spinors (n and/or p = 1) with non-square matrices.)

Comment: An analogous factorization (**almost as important as** $PAP^{-1}$) is the factorization $PAP^T$ which occurs quite naturally in the case of quadratic forms (https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoeldsee263/15-symm.pdf) which addresses symmetric matrices $A$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Exactly the sort of answer I was hoping for, and with a very clear explanation in the link. Merci beaucoup!